# how to solve uninitialized constant error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 3 tables `categories`with fields id,name,parent_id, `coaches` with id, name and join table  `categories_coaches` with category_id and coach_id. i want join  two table (categories_coaches and categories) with category_id and get the parent_id. when i run this  please give me a solution for this

here is my code

**Models**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches
end

class Coaches < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

**View/new.html.erb**

`<%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@category.coaches, 'id', 'name')%>`

controller

`class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end`

when i try this iam getting this error

[image]

Comment: Your model name and the associations are wrong, you should have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: use `CategoryCoaches` not `CategoriesCoaches`

Comment: Instead of using images kindly mention the error in the question. It helps other users with same errors to find this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your models by the singular name format.

You also need to make sure your associations reflect whether they are singular or plural (`belongs_to` is singular):

```
class CategoryCoach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

This also goes for the other association:

```
#app/models/coach.rb
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :category_coaches
end
```

---

**ActiveRecord**

You need to work on your ActiveRecord associations. Specifically, you've associated your models in a peculiar way.

I'd use a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association:

```
#app/models/coach.rb
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches
end
```

You'd need a join table with the following:

```
#categories_coaches
category_id | coach_id
```

This will give you the ability to call `@category.coaches` etc:

[image]

---

**Structure**

I think there's a deeper structural issue to content with.

Firstly, why have you embedded your *ProgrammesController* in a *namespace*? The namespace has nothing to do with your controller structure - it just provides a way to segregate functionality in your app.

You should structure your app like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :coaches do
    resources :programmes #-> url.com/coaches/:coach_id/programmes/new
end

#app/models/coach.rb
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :programmes
end

#app/models/programme.rb
class Programme < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :coach
end

#app/controllers/programmes_controller.rb
class ProgrammesController < ApplicationController
    def new 
       @coach = Coach.find params[:coach_id]
       @programme = @coach.programmes.new
    end
    def create
       @coach = Coach.find params[:coach_id]
       @programme = @coach.programmes.new programme_params
       @programme.save
    end 

    private

    def programme_params
       params.require(:programme).permit(:x, :y, :z)
    end
end
```

Comment: Also isn't `has_many :categories_coaches` should be `has_many :category_coaches`?

Comment: Yes, I was just writing that ^_^, thanks for the prompt!

Comment: @RichPeck .. Please see the updation in my code and question

Answer (score 0):

Your association is mis-named:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_coaches
end
```